# How can I change an Android component's parent?

Tags: android, layout

I'm working with an Android layout which has two parts: a `RelativeLayout` full of buttons (`child`), and another `RelativeLayout` which holds the previous plus a few more buttons (`parent`). Here's a little illustration if it helps:

```
  v child       v parent
+-Rel---------+-Rel-+
| BTN BTN     | BTN |
| BTN BTN BTN |     |
|     BTN BTN | BTN |
+-------------+     |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

I want to programmatically move one button from the outer `RelativeLayout` to the inner one for certain circumstances. **How can I do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another workaround (just a suggestion) would be setting the buttons Visibility with `GONE` and `VISIBLE`.
Even though it does`t answer your question, it solves your problem.

> public void setVisibility (int visibility)
>
> Added in API level 1 Set the enabled state of this view.
>
> Related XML Attributes android:visibility Parameters visibility   One of
>   VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, or GONE.
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this and just duplicating the button.